# Clarification over In-Order traversal in binary search tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I'm studying Trees in Java, and came across some confusing lines in the book I'm studying. The diagram given for the in-order traversal is this:

[image]

The code for the traversal (recursive) is:

```
private void inOrder(Node leftRoot) {
    if (localRoot != null) {
        inOrder(localRoot.leftChild);
        System.out.println(localRoot.iData + " ");
        inOrder(localRoot.rightChild);
    }
 }
```

The lines I'm confused at are:

> Now we’re back to inOrder(A), just returning from traversing A’s left
> child. We visit A and then call inOrder() again with C as an argument,
> creating inOrder(C). Like inOrder(B), inOrder(C) has no children, so
> step 1 returns with no action, step 2 visits C, and step 3 returns
> with no action. **inOrder(B) now returns to inOrder(A)**.
>
> However,
> inOrder(A) is now done, so it returns and the entire traversal is
> complete. **The order in which the nodes were visited is A, B, C**; they
> have been visited inorder. In a binary search tree this would be the
> order of ascending keys.

I've highlighted the parts where I'm stuck at. First, I think in the third step, inOrder(C)[and not inOrder(B)] returns to inOrder(A).And second, the order in which the nodes were visited should be B -> A -> C.

Please help me out!

Comment: Since the System.out.println(localRoot.iData + " "); is in the second row, this print out(or visit) order should be B->A->C. But the real access order it A->B->C.

Comment: You are correct in both claims.

Comment: @Shloim it's Robert Lafore's Data Structures and Algorithms as I mention in my answer below. A fairly good book for beginners, but I do remember being frustrated there were no published errata when I was learning from it.

Comment: It's the book [Data Structures & Algorithms in Java - Robert Lafore](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Java-Edition/dp/0672324539)

Comment: I'll just recommend this one, and let you go on your way.
https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms

Comment: As a sidenote Manish, check out the diagram for in order  traversal [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#/media/File:Sorted_binary_tree_inorder.svg). It helps explain what Roger Dwan means above about access order vs visit order. The long curvy path represents accesses, the dots represent visits. What's even cooler is that pre order and post order traversal use the same curvy path, just putting the dots in different places (see the rest of the wiki article for these images).

Comment: The link is helpful, thanks! I see they've mentioned the in-order traversal as **In-order: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I**. In that case, what would be the traversal order in this example? Now I'm confused with the traversal order and visit order and access order!

Comment: The confusing thing about Lafore's example (besides the mistakes) is that it isn't actually sorted. I.e. B is not "less than" A (by normal alphabetical sort). If he made B the root, with left child A and right child C, then the in order traversal would yield (A, B, C), which is more obviously sensible, since it is, you know... **in order**. I personally prefer BST traversal examples to use numbers rather than letters. "Access order" only refers to the order in which the method is called on each node... but this is not something which is usually of much concern when discussing tree traversals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on both counts. These seem to be typos, or *errata*.

As a sidenote, I recognized the diagram style in your post because I learned data structures years ago from the same book (Lafore). Unfortunately it does not seem that he has a list of errata published anywhere, which is disappointing, since most authors do strive to do this.

Comment: The second claim is not an error. As @RogerDwan explained, the book is referring to the **visit order** which is A,B,C, not the **output order** which is B,A,C.

Comment: He clearly states that "they have been visited inorder. In a binary search tree this would be the order of ascending keys." so either he is mistaken or he defined "visit order" in 2 different ways in the same sentence.

Comment: If both picture and code is from that book, it should be fix because both picture and code are show its "VISIT ACTION" at the second line. I think that's why @Manish confused about.

Comment: I think @Shloim is right. As far as I think, visit order should mean the **traversal** order, which again should be the same as the output order, as per the code defined in the recursive method.Or is the visit order different from traversal order?

Comment: Good job finding that out. This subject is confusing enough even when you're not dealing with erroneous sentences.

Comment: @Manish usually in this context, the terms visit, traverse, and process can be used interchangeably. So yes as you expect, visit order is indeed traversal order. Although again as Roger Dwan pointed out, the nodes are "accessed" (i.e. touched) in a different order than the visit order.